# Error to connect on server using Spring Cloud Config: `Connect: Timeout Exception on Url`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-config

I'm executing a Spring application local that get properties data from a server application on k8s. At first moment everything working fine, but today the connection is stopped. When start Spring app client I got:

```
2020-07-24 11:16:58.780  INFO 24372 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : https://my-server-url:443
2020-07-24 11:16:59.151  INFO 24372 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - https://my-server-url:443. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-07-24 11:16:59.151  WARN 24372 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "https://my-server-url:443/app-name/local": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2020-07-24 11:16:59.153  INFO 24372 --- [           main] .s.g.TransactionSearchGatewayApplication : The following profiles are active: local
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app-name
---
spring:
  profiles: local
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: https://my-server-url:443
      skipSslValidation: true
```

The connection between local <-> k8s is working because I tried from browser and got UP connection.

```
https://my-server-url:443/actuator/health
```

I tried:

- Restart app on k8s;
- Set `fail-fast` and `retry` props on bootstrap.yml;
- Reset router;
- Re-clone application;
- Invalidate caches and restart;
- Reinstall JDK 13.

Nothing works.

Comment: It appears [`ConfigClientProperties`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/v3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigClientProperties.java#L37) does not support any SslValidation settings, but you may be able to [use a custom `RestTemplate`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#custom-rest-template) (or, of course, actually teach the JVM to trust the CA of that endpoint)

Comment: Stuck with the same issue. How did you resolve it?